# Upload imagefield Django

Tags: django, image, django-urls, media-url

I need help please.
I want to upload my images but there's a problem [A screenshot of what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPddQ.png) 
I uploaded my images dynamically, 
In the model I have:

```
....
class Visage(models.Model):
    personne = models.ForeignKey(Personne)

    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        return "personne/static/personne/Images/%s/%s"% (self.personne.nom,filename)

    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to=generate_filename)
    ...
```

In the template I have:

```
{% for image in visages_liste %}
        <a href="{{image.image.url }}"> <img src="{{image.image.url}}" height="420"></a>
    {% endfor %}
```

the url of the image looks like: localhost:8000/personne/static/personne/Images/NameOfThePerson/NameOfTheImage.jpg

The view :

```
class IndexView (generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'personne/accueil.html'
    context_object_name = 'visages_liste'


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Visage.objects.all()
```

In the urls I've tried so many different things but no one worked.
What do I should put in the STATIC_MEDIA and the STATIC_URL ?
and what to put in the urls to work ?

Comment: When you say the url of the image is `/home/user/projet/personne/static/personne/Images/NameOfThePerson/NameOfTheImage.jpg`, is this the path where the image is stored, or is this the path that the browser is trying to render?

Comment: Both of them
the path where the image is stored is : /home/user/projet/personne/static/personne/Images/NameOfThePerson/NameOfTheImag‌​e.jpg
the link that the browser shows : http://localhost:8000/home/user/projet/personne/static/personne/Images/NameOfThePerson/NameOfTheImag‌​e.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `settings.py`, try setting your `MEDIA_ROOT` to:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

And in your project's `urls.py` file add:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns

# Add this to the end of the urls.py file, after your other urls
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}))
```

Comment: I believe @Leonard2's answer is correct for your case, as you shouldn't have `MEDIA_ROOT` in your `generate_filename` method. Update your method to match, and also make sure you have the `urls.py` snippet from my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

`upload_to` of `ImageField` needs to be the subroot after `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`.

Instead of

```
ImageField(blank=False, upload_to=os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'personee'))
```

please try

```
ImageField(blank=False, upload_to='personne')
```

then the image will be save in `MEDIA_ROOT/personne`.

**EDIT:**
with your model setting,

Instead of

```
def generate_filename(self, filename):
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'personne/static/personne/Images/'))+'/' + self.personne.nom+'/'+ filename
```

please try

```
def generate_filename(self):
    return 'personne/static/personne/Images/'+self.personne.nom
```

then the image will be uploaded in MEDIA_ROOT/personne/static/... as specified.

Comment: The ImageField must be uploaded in a folder that has the name of the person. That's why I have:  upload_to="..+self.personne.nom+'/'+ filename"

Comment: @Lilia what I want to address is that `MEDIA_ROOT` is not needed for `upload_to`. how about the edited answer?

Comment: At first, it was like this, but I had the same problems.

Comment: I want to upload my images in a template

Comment: I agree with @Leonard2; you can still generate the path, but Django will automatically append your path to the `MEDIA_ROOT`. So it might be wise to remove the `MEDIA_ROOT` from your `generate_filename` method. Otherwise, you risk having your images be located at `/path/to/media/path/to/media/personne/...`. Note the duplicate `/path/to/media/`

Comment: I edited my question now.
The path that the browser shows is localhost:8000/personne/static/personne/Images/Person'sName/Image'sName.jpg

Comment: @CurtisOlson I changed it and tried your answer. It solved my problem.

Comment: Excellent, glad @Leonard2 and I could help

Comment: I am also glad it helped! And thanks for the help @Curtis :]